# Convert mysql query to JPQL query

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpql

How can i state the following mysql query in JPQL

```
select * from Price WHERE `valueDate` = (SELECT MAX(`valueDate`) FROM Price) and fundId = 2930
```

what i have tried is the following:

```
"select a from Price a where a.valueDate = select MAX(a.valueDate) and a.fund.id = :" +Price.QUERY_PARAM_FUND_ID
```

but get errors on that approach :

```
Caused by: <openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: "Encountered "MAX" at character 50, but expected: ["AND", "GROUP", "HAVING", "OR", "ORDER", <EOF>]." while parsing JPQL "select a from Price a where a.valueDate = select MAX(b.valueDate) from Price b and a.fund.id = :fundId"
```

Comment: Please show some effort by showing what you have tried. People will be more keen to help, and your question more likely to remain unclosed.

Comment: hi there, i have added my attempts. thanks for the reply

Comment: What is the error ? Can you paste it here ?

Comment: Caused by: <openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: "Encountered "MAX" at character 50, but expected: ["AND", "GROUP", "HAVING", "OR", "ORDER", <EOF>]." while parsing JPQL "select a from Price a where a.valueDate = select MAX(b.valueDate) from Price b and a.fund.id = :fundId".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will work if you will added bracket before and after sub-query like.

"select a from Price a where a.valueDate = (select MAX(a.valueDate) from Price) and a.fund.id = :" +Price.QUERY_PARAM_FUND_ID

else let me say some thing related to hibernate implementation of JPA Specification.
If you have Hibernate model named 'Price' and you are going to do query through that model then. the HQL will be like that

```
try {
    final StringBuilder qry = new StringBuilder();
    qry.append(" SELECT")
            .append(" FROM Price p")
            .append(" WHERE p.valueDate = (SELECT MAX(pr.valueDate) FROM Price pr)")
            .append(" AND p.fundId = :fundId");
    return getJpaTemplate().execute(new JpaCallback() {
        public Object doInJpa(EntityManager em)
                throws PersistenceException {
            Query q = em.createQuery(qry.toString());
            q.setParameter("fundId", fundId);
            return q.getResultList();
        }
    });
} catch (RuntimeException re) {}
```

Comment: fine @AndreCoetzee have a nice time